# How to detect if the scrollview stops scrolling in nativescript angular?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Iam developing android and ios application using nativescript angular.Iam using scrollview to show list items.Is there anyway to detect if user stopped scrolling in scrollview? Please provide any solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen to the `touch` event and make sure `event.action` is [TouchAction.up](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_gestures_.touchaction#up).

**Edit:**  If you want to attach your own implementation of `UIScrollViewDelegate` on iOS, you could do this. My version of delegate accepts the original delegate as a parameter, so I don't loose anything that is already implemented in the original delegate.

```
(<any>ScrollView.prototype).originalAttachNative = (<any>ScrollView.prototype).attachNative;
(<any>ScrollView.prototype).attachNative = function () {
    this.originalAttachNative();
    const newDelegate = MyUIScrollViewDelegateImpl.initWithOriginalDelegate(this._delegate);
    this._delegate = newDelegate;
    this.nativeViewProtected.delegate = newDelegate;
};
```

Comment: Ok this is for user stop the scrolling.if scroll stops automatically any events fired?

Comment: I don't think there is a scroll end event, but you could listen to `scroll` event and add a delay of let's say 300ms, if you receive your next scroll event within that time it's still scrolling, otherwise scroll is stopped.

Comment: Ok thank you..i will check. and one more question i want to ask you Can i access the native api's for scroll events  from ios and android?

Comment: Yes, of course. All the native apis are open to you on both iOS & Android.

Comment: Hai manoj i have implement the scrollview delegate to my typescript class. can you tell me how to set the delegate to my scrollview?

Comment: Updated my answer with code snippet to update the delegate. You could do this in app module or main file, make sure you do the condition check to run this code only on iOS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188647/discussion-between-arigarasuthan-and-manoj).